# IE 7 and 8 are having issue with use indexOf with array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am facing issue with `indexOf()` of JavaScript with array values.
below given code is not working IE 7, 8

e.g.

```
var wildcards2 = ['test1', 'test2'];
var test = wildcards2.indexOf('test2');
alert(test);
```

but working fine in Mozila

After this result, there is ajax request in may page.
But just because it is not working so , page get submitted instead of sending ajax request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexOf` for `Array` objects was added in JavaScript 1.6 but IE 7 and 8's JS implementations are closer to JavaScript 1.5 and they do not support `indexOf`.

The [MDN documentation for `indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) includes a compatibility routine that you can copy/paste.

Alternatively, some libraries implement helper functions to provide similar functionality, and you can use them:

- [`indexOf` from the YUI 3 array module](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Array.html#yui_3_7_3_2_1352452705442_1130)
- jQuery [`inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Comment: I think that you meant to refer to the "$.inArray" jQuery method instead of "each".